# jquery activate function running before tab switch

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Running jquery 1.9.1 tab functionality and trying to change a background image on tab activation.  Somewhat new to jquery, and decided to detect the activated tab by looking to see if the aria-expanded tag has been set to true.  If so, I grab a custom tag that I've inserted with the image url for that tab (called bgimg, e.g., bgimg="url(/images/tab1img.png")) and make the change.  But, it seems that whatever's in the activate section of the tabs call is running before the aria-expanded is set to true for the selected tab.  Is this the case?  If so, how can I trigger the function so it runs after the new tab is activated?

Here is the jquery:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            setBGImg();
        }
    });
    setBGImg();

    function setBGImg() {
        $('.ui-tabs-panel').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
                $('#backgroundImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('bgImg') + ')');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are jQuery events for pretty much everything.

You can set a custom handler before activationg a tab, this is [documented here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate).

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to Target the new Panel from the tools JQuery UI gives you.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {

        //ui.newPanel lets you target the new Panel
        var panel = ui.newPanel;
        panel.css({'background-color': 'blue'});
    }
});
```

There are a couple of things you can target through the `ui` parameter.
 - newPanel
 - newTab
 - oldPanel
 - oldTab

HERE IS A [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qGmn8/) that shows it in action.